# Get all indexed classes without ContextHelper

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

What is the recommended way to get all indexed classes?

I've found this:

```java
ContextHelper.getSearchFactory(session)
    .getIndexedTypesPolymorphic(new Class[]{Object.class})
```

but ContextHelper is deprecated and I would prefer to avoid deprecated methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no recommended way to access the internal metadata, but being this a frequently requested feature it is likely to be implemented soon.

You could use this:

```java
SearchFactory searchFactory = Search.getFullTextSession(session).getSearchFactory();
SearchFactoryImplementor searchFactoryInternals = (SearchFactoryImplementor) searchFactory;
Set<Class<?>> indexedTypes = searchFactoryInternals.getIndexedTypesPolymorphic(new Class[]{Object.class});
```

But this cast is revealing internals which might not be maintained in the next version (backwards compatibility might break without notice).